# Arch + LXDE + lxdm -> INIT: Id "x" respawning too fast: Disabled for 5 minutes

Tags: arch-linux, lxde

I've been trying to install LXDE with lxdm on Arch, and followed the instructions given at archlinux.org and lxde.org on how to set these things up together.

Here's the manipulations I make to `inittab`:

```
# Boot to X11
id:5:initdefault:
```

and add:

```
x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/lxdm >& /dev/null
xt:5:wait:/usr/bin/chvt 7
```

just as I'm told to do from the 2 websites. The final result I get is:

`INIT: Id "x" respawning too fast: Disabled for 5 minutes`

I tried manipulating things so that I might get it to work but it doesn't!

Thanks so much for any helps ;-)

Comment: When are you getting your error message? Have you tried the daemon method (adding `lxdm` to the DAEMONS array in `rc.conf`)? Is `lang=1` in `lxdm.conf`?

Comment: I just tried the daemon mode. Is it more than adding the word lxdm in the end of parentheses? It doesn't work, but here's something: In both `lxdm.log` and `Xorg.0.log` I have `Fatal server error. No screens found` and I don't have an `xorg.conf`, but how do I generate one?

Comment: and yeah, the `lang=1` is there.

Comment: Generated an `xorg.conf` here in Ubuntu and moved it to Arch's X11 directory, but doesn't work. I'm getting to believe that there's some package or something that I haven't installed and also main instructions in lxde.org and archlinux.org are imcomplete. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the `xorg-server` and `xorg-xinit` packages installed? And the appropriate driver for your card?

Comment: `xorg-server`: yes
`xorg-xinit`: don't know
`driver`: How do I know the package name? (I use an NVIDIA card.)

Comment: @Kevin you were right. I had not installed xorg-xinit and also the driver. I installed them and now its set up and working. And also I appreciate your knowledge on X. ;-)

Comment: @Kevin please write it as an answer so I will click accept. Helps others facing a similar case!

Comment: Posted, glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run an x server, the main packages to install are `xorg-server`, `xorg-xinit`, and whichever driver you need for your system.  Ensure you have all three of those packages, `xorg-xinit` in particular seems to commonly be forgotten or overlooked.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I did what you said and I'm right now writing this post from my Arch-LXDE! In fact the reason I believe I wasn't able to get it done was my lack of knowledge on structure of X. I still don't know enough about it and gotta study it, but thanks so much for getting me going! ;-)